# Java - Web Scraper Issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to scrape this page https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/cleveland-cavaliers but I need the grid that displays when you click 'Betting View'... I'm having some trouble. Is it even possible with the code I have? I'm getting null when I print div.

```
    String teamLink = "https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/team/cleveland-cavaliers/.betting"; // + Teams[i] + "/";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(teamLink).get();

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(teamLink);
    final HtmlDivision div = page.getFirstByXPath("div.btn-group");

    System.out.println(div);
    page = div.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to click the button. The data from both tabs seems to be in both tabs. The button appears to run a JavaScript function that shows and hides columns. Just fetch the whole table with ID `DataTables_Table_0` and trash the columns you don't care about.

Comment: Thanks... it's late. I don't know what I was thinking on that.

Comment: Glad to help bud.